# How to highlight :active element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you click a post on stackoverflow it will directly go to the specific thread and jump off to the right place at the page. I get it.

But how to do that highlighting part? You know the whole div become light orange and fadeout the color. How to color that specific post and fade out the color?
Here I attached a screenshot

[image: [1]: https://s3.postimg.org/h69jgu58z/2016_09_12_14_30_07.jpg]

Comment: Do you have an example of such a link ?

Comment: It is just a color `transition`, executed by JS after jump to `anchor`. Have you tried something?

Comment: @DenysSéguret [Here's one such link to your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446702/how-stackoverflow-color-the-specific-post-when-navigate-to-it#comment66215259_39446702). (You may need to open it in a new tab to trigger the effect)

Comment: They bound hashchange event (namespace 'highlightDestination')  to `window`

Comment: @eisbehr This question looks valid to me, how to search for it might be not so immediate for somebody new to that field. Someone should probably answer the question and you look qualified for that. BTW here's how I do the exact same thing in my Miaou chat: [JS part](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/src/main-js/miaou.md.interact.js#L138), [CSS part](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/src/main-scss/chat.scss#L872).

Comment: @eisbehr That will certainly be useful. Good.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically a `css transition` executed on `hashChange` event. So whenever the `hash` of the browsers url changes, a `event` gets triggered. Then you can execute whatever you want to.

In your question you want to start a `transition` of the `background-color`. In my example I use two `css` classes and a `setTimeout` to do this.

We need one class, `.transitionStart`, to change the `background` to `orange` instantly on event start. After a `timeout` of `0.5s` (*you can change that as you like*) I replace the class with `.transitionEnd`, to let css fade color back to white.

**And that's it!**

You can bind the same function to `window.onload` to highlight the element instantly one pageload too.

```js
function highlightHash() {
    var id = document.location.hash.substr(1);
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if( element ) {
        element.className = "transitionStart";
  
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.className = "transitionEnd";
        }, 500);
    }
};

window.onhashchange = highlightHash;

// this execute the highlighting on inital load too
window.onload = highlightHash;
```

```css
.transitionStart {
  background: orange;
}
.transitionEnd {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">highlight #one</a> - <a href="#two">highlight #two</a>
<br /><br />

<div id="one">#one</div>
<div id="two">#two</div>
```

Comment: This isn't what question want. Element should highlight on page load.

Comment: @Mohammad I wrote exactly this in my answer. Great you don't read the text before posting a comment. But just for you, It workes now on page load too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get URL hash using `window.location.hash` and find element has `id` equal to hash. Then add your css or class to selected element.

```js
window.location.hash = "second"; // you can use `first` or `third`
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window.location.hash).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">First</div>
<div id="second">Second</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
```

*In above example, if your change `window.location.hash` to another id, relevant element highlight.*